# Cant Get My Data Deleted Properly From React-ExpressJS App CRUD Delete Request

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, api, express

I have managed to delete a query only with this code, but, it is not
deleting the query I clicked on, it deletes the query next to it with some kind of weird order...

I tried:
findByIdAndDelete(req.body.id); is not working!
findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id); is also not working!

Backend:

```
app.delete('/showlist-fromdb/:id', async (req, res) => {
  try{ 
    //was findOneAndRemove(req.body.title);
      await List.findOneAndRemove(req.body.id);
     
      return res.status(200).json({ success: true, msg: 'Product Deleted' });
  }
  catch(err){
      console.error(err);
  }
});
```

Frontend

```
export const deleteListing = async (idHolder) =>{
    /**DELETE METHOD */
    const options =  await{
      url: `http://localhost:5001/showlist-fromdb/:id${idHolder}`,
      method: 'DELETE',
      data: idHolder
    };
    
    axios(options)
    .then(response => {
      console.log('A listing got deleted!')
    }).catch((err)=>{console.log(err)})
    

}
```

Comment: try removing async await, if you are using `.then()` you don't need it and I don't think that your `const otpions ` needs an await